# Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one

Tags: android, eclipse

When I import a new existing project into Eclipse, I get the following error message when attempting to execute as an Android project:

> Project has no target set. Edit the
>   project properties to set one

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using eclipse Juno, and there is no such menu as 
Project » Properties » Java Build Path anywhere.

Closest menu entry is Window->preferences->android but in that menu it is not possible to remove any entries.

My solution now is to create another project with files having the exact same name as the original project and then manually copy and paste the code.

Comment: Are you serious? What about @Igor Ganapolsky's answer? That one seems to be working out better.

Answer (score 47):

I got this error on the command line when I ran `./android update project -p .` Basically I had to specify a target like so in order for it to work:
`./android update project -p . --target android-10`

Answer (score 8):

From the comments of [this article](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-(Android)):

```
[2009-05-27 12:18:36 - DroidGap] Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
[2009-05-27 12:18:38 - DroidGap] no classfiles specified
[2009-05-27 12:18:38 - DroidGap] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

> I was able to solve this on the `Projects > Properties > Android` screen by:
>
> - first selecting Google APIs (which was incorrect for my setup)
> - and then reselecting Android 1.5 (which is correct and had previously been selected).
>
> I was immediately able to run the emulator following this change.

Answer (score 8):

My problem was that the target specified inside the *project.properties* file was not installed. It was "target=android-3", which is the Cupcake target.

I solved it by increasing the number to 8 (Froyo API) which is the oldest API level I had installed in my environment.

Comment: A colleague of mine had this same problem when using the Facebook SDK project (target-8). Rather than adjust that number to fit in with whatever he had installed, we just got him to install SDK 8.

Comment: The command _android list targets_ can also help to verify your possible targets.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I copied the project folder 'google-play-services_lib' alone after separating it from its actual folder structure into my workspace  and referenced it in my project.
But I could resolve the error by referencing the project folder 'google-play-services_lib' with out separating it from its actual folder structure.
Actual folder structure:
google_play_services > libproject > google-play-services_lib.

Hope this helps!!!!!-)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y" (in my case Android 1.5). click OK. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK. That should work.

It is also possible that you have a JAR file located somewhere in your project folders (I had copied the Admob JAR file into my src folder) and THEN added it as a Java Path Library. It does not show up under the Package Explorer, so you don't notice it, but it does get counted twice, causing the dreaded Dalvik error 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you firstly put the project files in the resourse path. Try to put the project in another file, and reimport it. It will work!!!

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved my issue by setting the higher target.
go to windows->preference->android and check on higher API available and click apply.

might work for you also.