# Error: NetBeans 7.0 Android SDK 14

Tags: android

I am getting the following error on NetBeans 7.0 trying to run a HelloAndroid application. The Android SDK as well as an Android device have already been detected by NetBeans, and I followed all the instructions given.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:421: Android Target is not set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292416/project-has-no-target-set-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue. It has to do with how the Android application is build in the new version of the SDK. Here is what helped for me: Go to your Project Properties file you will find something like

```
target=android-10
```

I think you can safely delete this. However Netbeans will create it again if you go to the properties of the project by using right click.

Go to Pre-user properties file. There should already be a setting sdk.dir which shows the path to your sdk directory. Add a new setting:

`target.api=android-10`

As you may have guessed, replace `android-10` with the API Version you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think its problem in build.xml. Find this file in left windows.

Find in build.xml this code:
`<property file="default.properties" />`

change with : `<property file="project.properties" />`

save..and finish...
run again

sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

Thanks last_id, it works :-). But the build.xml will be overwritten everytime you change the android target device. There should be a better solution - may be, the android plugin has a bug?

However, I do the following now as a workaround.

Either

1) Adding `<property file="project.properties" />` or overwriting `<property file="default.properties" />`, as you suggest, and then mark the file as "read only". There may be no reason to change it anymore. Pay attention: removing the project by NetBeans itself won't work completely.

or

2) for Linux/U**x: not 1), but replacing the empty (!) file default.properties by a sym-link to project.properties. So, project.properties may change, but it doesn't matter :-). And a later removing of the project will work.