# Error in importing project n eclipse

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a project to Eclipse. Do import. Eclipse write

```
Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
```

What to do? Added to the project, but all the files are empty.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292416/project-has-no-target-set-edit-the-project-properties-to-set-one

Answer (score 1):

`Right click on your project` --> `Android` --> `Selecte a proper android version.`

This will solve your porblem